# Merge two sql queries into one

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been working on a system service for a client for a while and need some help, I need to merge two sql queries into one. The first part of the query is to look at the master sequence number and count it, after which the query must update a field. I have the two queries below if anyone can help with this problem.

**Count query**

```
 SELECT master_seq, count(master_seq) as NofH
 FROM [ZS_CS_EVO_Integration].[dbo].[CS_Consolidation]
 where delivery_date = '2016-07-01'
 GROUP BY master_seq
 order by master_seq
```

**Update Query**

```
 (" UPDATE [dbo].[CS_Consolidation]"
+ " SET [split_dlv] = 1"
+ " FROM [dbo].[CS_Consolidation]"
+ " WHERE"
+ " [master_seq] <> 0 AND CONVERT(DATE,delivery_date) = '" + yesterday + "'", IntConnect);
```

Comment: How are this two query's connected?

Comment: @gofr1 this is what i tried doing but it is wrong                                                UPDATE [dbo].[CS_Consolidation] SET [split_dlv] = 1 FROM [dbo].[CS_Consolidation] WHERE SELECT COUNT[master_seq] > 1 AND delivery_date = '2016-08-15'

Comment: So, you need to take all `master_seq` with `COUNT(*)>1` and UPDATE your table? And `delivery_date` should be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the first part into CTE, then join and UPDATE:

```
DECLARE @delivery_date DATE = '2016-07-01'

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT master_seq
    FROM [ZS_CS_EVO_Integration].[dbo].[CS_Consolidation]
    where delivery_date = @delivery_date and [master_seq] <> 0 
    GROUP BY master_seq
    HAVING count(master_seq) > 1
)

UPDATE c
SET [split_dlv] = 1
FROM [dbo].[CS_Consolidation] c
INNER JOIN cte t
    ON t.master_seq = c.master_seq and c.delivery_date = @delivery_date
```